# Pinterest and Wordpress, invalid url when I share images

Tags: wordpress, plugins, share, pinterest

I have a wordpress website where I’m using a plugin to share and pin images on Pinterest. Now I’m using the plugin called “share this image” but I’ve tried also with others plugins and I always have the same issue.

The problem is that when I try to share an image in Pinterest (the problem is only on Pinterest), I click on the share button, be redirected on Pinterest, I select the board and I get the message “Sorry, something went wrong. Please make sure the URL is correct and try again.”

Anyone have any idea why I have this problem and can help me to solve it?

[That's the website](https://www.kettyagnesani.it/la-bottega/)

Comment: I don't know what other details are necessary to understand and limit the problem.

Comment: Do you get any errors? Is anything printed in the developer console of your browser? I’m not sure how anyone would be able to help you without more details.